# How to add a ratio parameter to scipy signal convolution in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, scipy, signal-processing, convolution

I am working on a convolution reverb in Python and convolution using scipy's 
convolve method works great. But when I try to add a ratio-attribute to control how much reverb should be in the sum signal it does not work:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def addReverb(data, ir_data, ratio=1.0):
    verb = np.multiply(ir_data, ratio)
    verbed_data = signal.convolve(data, verb, method='fft')
    return verbed_data
```

I made sure that both signals (dry data and impulse response) habe the same samplerate. How could I control the ratio of dry signal to room signal?

Comment: Seems like maybe it would be best to say that the signal created with 'addReverb' is to be seen as the total wet signal and should be added to the dry signal within another method via its own ratio like: mixed_signal = dry_signal + ratio * wet_signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you're asking for by adding `verb[0]+=(1.0-ratio)` after the multiply.

That's not how reverb works, though.  Applying your ratio will make the reverberations quieter, but they will last just as long. In the real world, "less reverberation" means that the reverberations will die out much more quickly.

You could probably make something sounding better like this:

```
def addReverb(data, ir_data, ratio=1.0):
    verb = np.abs(ir_data)
    verb = np.multiply(verb, 1.0/np.max(verb)) # make sure the highest value is 1
    verb = np.power(verb, 1.0/ratio) # a higher power makes the reverb die out more quickly
    verbed_data = signal.convolve(data, verb, method='fft')
    return verbed_data
```

This procedure is a little dodgy.  It assumes the reverb is made by delayed sharp echos and applies your ratio to all of those echos.

It would really be better to go back to the process that generated `ir_data` and redo it with different parameters.